# httpd.conf multiple virtual hosts

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost

Coding for PHP on Mac OSX Lion, using the following within the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/user/Sites/wordpress
    ServerName wordpress.local
    <Directory “/Users/user/Sites/wordpress">
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 wordpress.local
```

This all works fine. What I want to be able to do is allow that first section to accept some sort of wildcard so that I can add several pages to the hosts file, but not have to keep messing with the httpd.conf file. I used to be able to use %1 and %0 instead of the directory name to get this working, but there now seems to be a problem with that.

All help much appreciated.

Cheers,
David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following blogpost by Rob Allen should help, I think : [**Automatic Apache vhosts**](http://akrabat.com/computing/automatic-apache-vhosts/)

The first part of the article is about [**`mod_vhost_alias`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), which will allow you to use wildcards for **`ServerAlias`**, a [**`VirtualDocumentRoot`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) directive it adds, and **`Directory`**.